# Binaryproto mean size different from cnn size

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, caffe

I'm trying to use the EmotiW_VGG_S caffemodel CNN. The mean_file binaryproto contains a 3x256x256 image that, I guess, I have to subtract from the image that I want to predict.

what I did to obtain the mean is:

```
def binaryproto2npy():
    proto_data = open(mean_file, "rb").read()
    a = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.BlobProto.FromString(proto_data)
    mean_values = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(a)[0]
    return mean_values
```

after that I load the mean_values, I tried to apply it to my image (a face) and classify it in this way:

```
def process_face(face, mean_values):
    image_dim = 256
    batch_size = 1
    channels = 3
    data = []
    resize = (image_dim, image_dim, 3)

    face = np.resize(face, (face.shape[0], face.shape[1], 1))

    if not ((face.shape[0] == resize[0]) & (face.shape[1] == resize[1])):
        face = caffe.io.resize_image(face, resize)

    # Setting up the right transformer for an input image
    transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': 
    net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
    transformer.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))
    transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2, 1, 0))
    transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)
    transformer.set_mean('data', mean_values)

    processed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', face)
    data.append(processed_image)

    net.blobs['data'].reshape(batch_size, channels, 224, 224)
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = data[0]
    out = net.forward()
```

the problem is that I tried this code but it seems that the mean and the image has a different shape and I'm not able to find a solution.